# Execution Timeout in C #

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I run my C# application I get an error reading:

> `execution timeout error occurred while loading fill combobox`.

The following is my code.

```
Connection con = new Connection();            
cmbVendorCode.Items.Clear();
con.dataGet("Select vendor_code from vendor_master order by vendor_code Asc;");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();            
con.sda.Fill(dt);
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Seems like Query execution timeout. If Yes please consider having Index on vendor_master table.

Comment: What is this `Connection` class?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you didn't use the `SqlDataAdapter` declaration, and you are using the object `sda` in  `con.sda.Fill(dt);` statement:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Query",con);
```

Write the fixed code using the above line of code :

```
Connection con = new Connection();    
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("*`<SelectionQuery>`*",con);        
cmbVendorCode.Items.Clear();
con.dataGet("Select vendor_code from vendor_master order by vendor_code Asc;");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();            
con.sda.Fill(dt);
```

Your problem should then be solved.